# Changing the colors on a image

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that allows me to change the colors of an image , through an interface you can choose a color, then clicking on the image you choose the color to be replaced by the one chosen in the interface but the problem is that :

I need to change the transformPoint method for recursively fill it with the image pixels that are similar to the pixel selected. The pixel where the click occurred is the reference pixel, clickedPoint in tramsformImage2, and color of paint is paintColor . The transformPoint method must paint the point if this is similar to the color of the reference pixel and then send their paint points north, south, est and west , this ( if any ) with the recursive method calls itself .

Because each method call stack requires this method of transforming the image is not feasible for areas that have a pixel where you need more than the existing stack .

```
public void transformImage2(Point clickedPoint, Color paintColor) {

    // desprezar o canal Alpha (transparÍncia) em todas as cores utilizadas
    int paintColorRGB = clearAlphaChannel(paintColor.getRGB());

    int deltaWidth = (imageWidth - label.getWidth()) / 2;
    int deltaHeight = (imageHeight - label.getHeight()) / 2;

    int x = clickedPoint.x + deltaWidth;
    int y = clickedPoint.y + deltaHeight;

    transformPoint(x, y, getPixelColor(clickedPoint), paintColorRGB);
}

private int getPixelColor(Point clickedPoint) {
    // desprezar o canal Alpha (transparÍncia) em todas as cores utilizadas
    int pixelColor = clearAlphaChannel(image.getRGB(clickedPoint.x,
            clickedPoint.y));

    return pixelColor;
}

private void transformPoint(int x, int y, int refColor, int paintColorRGB) {
    // desprezar o canal Alpha (transparÍncia) em todas as cores utilizadas
    int pixelRGB = clearAlphaChannel(image.getRGB(x, y));

    // TODO ...
    image.setRGB(x, y, paintColorRGB);
    // TODO ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, a recursive implementation can overflow the stack. You should try a queue implementation instead, see http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Flood_fill.html